# C++ call reference function from a const pointer

Tags: c++, function

I have a class with this function

```
class InputState
{
   public:
     key_map const & GetKeyMap();
}
```

then I have a const pointer:

```
InputState const * m_pInput;
```

How can I call that function from `m_pInput`?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you ask about, do you wonder about how to actually *call* the member function? Or do you wonder about any other error you get? Please show us what you have tried, and what possible errors you get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your function indeed does not modify the object itself, mark it as `const`:

```
 key_map const & GetKeyMap() const;
```

If it does modify, do not call it from a const pointer (or, well, use `const_cast` if absolutely needed).

Answer (score 1):

**If:** your member function doesn't alter the state of the object you add to it the `const` qualifier:

```
key_map const & GetKeyMap() const;
```

**Else:** use `const_cast`, which I don't recommend since it would break explicitly the `const`enss of your pointer, that might be for a reason in the first place:

```
const_cast<InputState*>(m_pInput)->GetKeyMap();
```

Comment: this is what i am looking for.